# How to backup a large FreeNAS?

Tags: mac, backup, freenas, incremental-backup, tape

We have a 12TB FreeNAS box in the office, and are looking for a way to keep a backup of it offsite.

We're considering (1) tape; (2) a bunch of bare drives (popped into a spare hotswap bay); (3) external drives. Any advice on which solution is best? (Online backup is not an option because our internet connection is too slow.)

And, is there some software that will keep track of which files have been backed up and which haven't? So that when one backup unit fills up, we can continue the backup on the next? (We don't want to have to back up to a 12TB device.)

This software could run, preferably, on the NAS itself; or from one of our Mac clients.

Our goal is a situation where

1. we attach some backup device;
2. it automatically fills up with stuff from the server; the contents of this unit are catalogued somewhere
3. something prompts us to replace with a fresh drive/tape;
4. backup continues until full, including any files that have changed since being backed up.

Answer (score 2):

Ze'ev,

You have several options.  [FreeNAS features list](http://www.freenas.org/features/feature-overview/item/backup-and-restore?category_id=108) states that it supports the following backup services:

```
Windows Shadow Copy
Apple Time Machine
[Amanda (plug-in)][2]
PC-BSD Life Preserver
```

FreeNas utilizes the powerful and flexible ZFS file system from Sun/Oracle.  Backing up ZFS snapshots is a relatively simple and painless process.  The [zfsbackup](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/zfsbackup/) tool appears to meet your needs for backing up snapshots, or you can script it yourself.

If you have another Solaris/BSD or FreeNAS system, or can get one, you can use the built in `zfs send` command to copy snapshots from one system to the other. [Here is Oracle's documentation on how to do it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6r4s/index.html#indexterm-546)